# Using vim -d, with two filenames, how do I set the second to read only (from the command line)?

Tags: vim

I'm regularly invoking `gvim -d` with two filenames; I'd like the second to be systematically opened in read only (since it's in a reference directory, and shouldn't be modified).  The first shouldn't be read only, however, because I'll be pulling some of the diffs from the second into it.  So what do I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: is it an idea to make the reference directory ... readonly? :)

Comment: That would be another (probably better) alternative, but it's not that simple.  The basic situation is that I'm working on a branch, and my reference directory is trunk (subversion checkouts).  And that I do have to make bug-fixes in trunk from time to time as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ gvim -d file1 file2 +'wincmd l | set ro | wincmd h'
```

does the trick.

Assuming you use bash, you can put it into an alias:

```
alias vd='/usr/bin/gvimdiff +"wincmd l | set ro | wincmd h"'
```

Comment: It works.  I'm actually invoking this via a bash function (using CygWin under Windows), so the equivalent of an alias is already there.  Thanks.